# Setting a boolean property from a 3rd party endpoint that returns a string

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, jsonconvert

I am attempting to deserialize a json object using JsonConvert - the data is coming from a 3rd party API

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserRegistration>(content,
                    JsonSnakeCaseNameStrategySettings.Settings());
```

The UserRegistration class:

```
public class UserRegistration
    {
        public UserRegistrationData UserRegistration { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserRegistrationData
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public UserRegistrationCustomFields CustomFields { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserRegistrationCustomFields
    {
        private bool emailDelivery;
        public string DeliveryTime { get; set; }

        public bool EmailDelivery {
            get
            {
                return emailDelivery;
            }
            set
            {
                emailDelivery = value.ToString() == "1";
            }
        }

        public bool SmsDelivery { get; set; }

        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

I've tried several ways, this is my current iteration.  The goal is to have "EmailDelivery" be a boolean, the value from the API will always be "1" or "0".  This throws a JsonReaderException: `Could not convert string to boolean: 0. Path 'user_registration.custom_fields.email_delivery', line 1, position 208.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need custom JsonConverter to modify the deserialize principle.

Change your model like below:

```
public class UserRegistrationCustomFields
{
    public string DeliveryTime { get; set; }

    public bool EmailDelivery{get;set;}

    public bool SmsDelivery { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Custom a JsonConverter:

```
public class JsonBooleanConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = reader.Value.ToString().ToLower().Trim();
        switch (value)
        {

            case "1": return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType == typeof(Boolean))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserRegistration>(json, new JsonBooleanConverter());
```